# Find the first column which starts with a string

Tags: regex, bash, awk, grep

I have a bash script which is going to receive a string that looks something like this:

```
foo,user:johndoe,bar
```

The order and number of values is not known, so it could also be something like:

```
bar,foo,baz,user:johndoe
```

I need to be able to get the name of the user -- in this case, `johndoe`.

With grep the closest I have gotten is this:

```
$ echo "foo,user:johndoe,bar" | grep -o 'user:.*,'
user:johndoe,
```

But this also gets me `user:` and `,`, which I don't want. I am new to this and am not sure if grep is the tool I should be using, or if awk or something is more appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simple substitutions sed will do:

```
% echo "foo,user:johndoe,bar" | sed 's/.*user:\([^,]*\).*/\1/'
johndoe
```

The above will replace the whole string with your user:

```
s/
  .*                     # Match anything zero or more times
    user:                # Match literal user:
         \([^,]*\)       # Capture everything but , zero or more times in \1
                  .*     # Match to the end of the string
                    /\1/ # Replace with what we matched and saved in \1
```

GNU Grep also have a `-P` option which enables PCRE that support [lookbehinds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind):

```
% echo "foo,user:johndoe,bar" | grep -Po '(?<=user:)[^,]*'
johndoe
```

`-P` is still highly experimental and should be avoided when possible.

Answer (score 2):

With awk:

```
$ echo "foo,user:johndoe,bar" | awk -F: '$1=="user"{print $2}' RS=,
johndoe
```

#### How it works

- `-F:`

  This sets the field separator to `:`
- `$1=="user"{print $2}`

  If the first field is `user`, then print the second field.
- `RS=,`

  This sets the record separator to `,`.

Comment: Interesting use of `FS` and `RS` combined :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "foo,user:johndoe,bar" | awk -F ":" '{print $2}' | awk -F "," '{print $1}'
```